# Using Python GUIZERO how to access textbox input data from a second window?

Tags: python, user-interface, guizero

I'm working on a UI project using guizero and I need to be able to extract user input data from a textbox on one window into another window where it will be used for a calculation. I have the bare bones of this up code up and running but when its time to transition to the next page, the data isn't saved and displayed on the next page. I know it's because I'm using a pushbutton to get to the next page and the textbox data is being saved before user has a chance to input something, but I don't know how to go about fixing this. I'm in the process of trying to teach myself UI development, I'd love some advice on what to do. Thanks in advance.

Code: https://github.com/Secretasianman77/Test-UI/blob/df90d08316f84d78e410fa87eada0d9e11692ca1/Test_UI_1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was tested with guizero 1.2.0. This is based on your code.

```
from guizero import *

app = App(title="Hello World", layout="auto")


def windowOne():
    window1 = Window(app, title="Input Test")
    userInput = TextBox(window1)
    #data = str(userInput.value)
    #unsure of why it wouldn't take data as arg
    nextPageButton = PushButton(window1, command=lambda:windowTwo(userInput.value), text="Next Page")


def windowTwo(x):
    window2=Window(app,title="Input Result Test")
    outputText = Text(window2, text="your data is:"+x)


windowOneButton = PushButton(app, command=windowOne, text="Next Page")

app.display()
```

Comment: Thank you!  This did it.

Comment: just wondering what are you trying to make?

Comment: I'm working on a smart agriculture project for my own learning, gratification, and as a potential future product.  Part of it involves building a user interface and that's what I'm building right now.